# Bash substring expansion on array

Tags: arrays, bash, substr, expansion

I have a set of files with a given suffix. For instance, I have a set of pdf files with suffix `.pdf`. I would like to obtain the names of the files without the suffix using substring expansion.

For a single file I can use:

```
file="test.pdf"
echo ${file:0 -4}
```

To do this operation for all files, I now tried:

```
files=( $(ls *.pdf) )
ff=( "${files[@]:0: -4}" )
echo ${ff[@]}
```

I now get an error saying that `substring expression < 0`..

( I would like to avoid using a `for` loop )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the `.pdf` part like so:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( *.pdf )
echo "${files[@]%.pdf}"
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` is always a good idea when using globs: it will make the glob expand to nothing if there are no matches.

`"${files[@]%.pdf}"` will expand to an array with all the trailing `.pdf` removed. You can, if you wish put this in another array as so:

```
files_noext=( "${files[@]%.pdf}" )
```

All this is 100% safe regarding funny symbols in filenames (spaces, newlines, etc.), except for the `echo` part for files named `-n.pdf`, `-e.pdf` and `-E.pdf`... but the `echo` was just here for demonstration purposes. Your `files=( $(ls *.pdf) )` is really really bad! *Do never parse the output of `ls`*.

---

To answer your comment: substring expansions don't work on each field of the array. Taken from the reference manual linked above:

> `${parameter:offset}`
>
> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
> If `offset` evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset from the end of the value of `parameter`. If `length` evaluates to a number less than zero, and `parameter` is not `@` and not an indexed or associative array, it is interpreted as an offset from the end of the value of `parameter` rather than a number of characters, and the expansion is the characters between the two offsets. If `parameter` is `@`, the result is `length` positional parameters beginning at offset. **If `parameter` is an indexed array name subscripted by `@` or `*`, the result is the `length` members of the array beginning with `${parameter[offset]}`.** A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the maximum index of the specified array. Substring expansion applied to an associative array produces undefined results.

So, e.g.,

```
$ array=( zero one two three four five six seven eight )
$ echo "${array[@]:3:2}"
three four
$
```

Comment: Does this mean that substring expansion does not work for arrays? (I also tried `echo "${files[@]:0: -3}"` and it does not work)