# Wget: read URL from file, add sequence of number to the URL

Tags: bash, variables

I am reading a file (with URL's) line by line:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    url=$line
    wget $url
    wget $url_{001..005}.jpg
done < $1
```

For first, I want to download primary url as you see `wget $url`. After that I want to add to the url sequence of numbers (_001.jpg, _002.jpg, _003.jpg, _004.jpg, _005.jpg):

```
wget $url_{001..005}.jpg
```

...but for some reason it's not working.

Sorry, missed out one thing: the url's are like `http://xy.com/052914.jpg`. Is there any easy way to add _001 before the extension?  `http://xy.com/052914_001.jpg`. Or I have to remove ".jpg" from the file containing URL's then simply add later to the variable?

Comment: Do all of the URLs have the same extension?

Comment: Yes, all URLs have .jpg extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try encapsulating your variable name:

```
wget ${url}_{001..005}.jpg
```

Bash is trying to expand the variable `$url_` in your command.

As for your jpg within the URL followup, see substring expansion in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
wget ${url:0: -4}_{001..005}.jpg
```

The `:0: -4` means, expand to the variable from position zero (the first character), minus the last 4 characters.

Or from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160838/bash-substring-expansion-on-array):

```
wget ${url%.jpg}_{001..005}.jpg
```

`%.jpg` removes `.jpg` specifically and will work on older versions of `bash`.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I just realized that I missed one point from my question (updated).

Answer (score 5):

Another way escaping the underscore char:

```
wget $url\_{001..005}.jpg
```